# USRP N210 on a vmware debian machine, connecting via an ethenet to USB adapter

Tags: virtual-machines, ethernet, adapter

For a professional project, I must fully automate a process which involves a GNURadio python flow played on an USRP N210. In order to acess the USRP, I installed a VMWare Debian machine on a Windows Computer (I need windows in order to acess another Electronic Device) However my computer has no ethernet port, so I plugged the ethernet cable coming from the USRP [the adapter setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEYmw.jpg) (it is an USRP from Ettus Research), and changed the IP of the Ethernet Interface[the ipv4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD5CS.png)[the ipv6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLkcO.png). I am not an expert at all in this domain, but I did this already on a Debian physical computer and it worked perfectly (same USRP, same cable, same adapter). I then tried to ping the USRP, through the new IP adress (XXX.XXX.XXX.21), it worked fine. I executed my automation to see if it worked, and on the logging, I could see the problem would come from USRP connecion. I pinged it again and it didn't work (Destination Host not reachable).

Here is my python code for my main fonction : [Code for main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HFiP.png). Change is nohing to vary about, it is only a text editing script.
Here is the code for sink. py :

from gnuradio import blocks
import pmt
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from gnuradio.fft import window
import sys
import signal
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from gnuradio.eng_arg import eng_float, intx
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import uhd
import time
import journal

class Top(gr.top_block):

```
def __init__(self):
    gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Not titled yet", catch_exceptions=True)

    ##################################################
    # Variables
    ##################################################
    self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 500000
    self.Freq = Freq = 868700000
    journal.log('Frequency and sample rate Ok')

    ##################################################
    # Blocks
    ##################################################
    journal.log("trying to reach usrp")
    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0 = uhd.usrp_sink(
        ",".join(("addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.102", "")),
        uhd.stream_args(
            cpu_format="fc32",
            args='',
            channels=list(range(0,1)),
        ),
        '',
    )
    journal.log("connection with usrp successful")
    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0.set_clock_source('external', 0)
    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0.set_samp_rate(samp_rate)
    # No synchronization enforced.

    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0.set_center_freq(uhd.tune_request(Freq,10*samp_rate), 0)
    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0.set_antenna('TX/RX', 0)
    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0.set_gain(1, 0)
    self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0 = blocks.multiply_const_cc(10)
    journal.log('trying to load file into flow')
    self.blocks_file_source_0 = blocks.file_source(gr.sizeof_gr_complex*1, '/home/eutelsat/Bureau/Simu/test2605.bin', False, 0, 0)
    journal.log('file loaded successfully')
    self.blocks_file_source_0.set_begin_tag(pmt.PMT_NIL)


    ##################################################
    # Connections
    ##################################################
    self.connect((self.blocks_file_source_0, 0), (self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0, 0))
    self.connect((self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0, 0), (self.uhd_usrp_sink_0, 0))


def get_samp_rate(self):
    return self.samp_rate

def set_samp_rate(self, samp_rate):
    self.samp_rate = samp_rate
    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0.set_samp_rate(self.samp_rate)
    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0.set_center_freq(uhd.tune_request(self.Freq,10*self.samp_rate), 0)

def get_Freq(self):
    return self.Freq

def set_Freq(self, Freq):
    self.Freq = Freq
    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0.set_center_freq(uhd.tune_request(self.Freq,10*self.samp_rate), 0)
```

[Then there is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXwyU.png)

Since then, when i unplug-plug, i have a short period of time to ping or connect with GNURadio, but after a few seconds/minutes, the USRP is still unreachable from the virtual machine. From my host computer, i can permaping the USRP. So the problem is that I cannot automate with some code a process that requires a frequent unplug. Can anyone help me on that ?